# Array list for all id

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array codes like that.

```
Array (
[0] => Array 
    (
        [name] => pen
        [id] => 12
    )    
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => pencil
        [id] => 34
    )       
[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => eraser
        [id] => 26
    )       
    .
    .
    .
    .       
[50] => Array
    (
        [name] => sharpener
        [id] => 53
    )    
)
```

I use `print_r($res[0]["id"])` for list one id but I want to list all id. How can we do that? Thanks.

Comment: use `foreach` to loop through

Comment: $a=count($res);
for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++){echo $res[$i]['id'];}

Comment: Thank you @mohade your code works fine but it's not work if I can use it on database. My code

$sql = "select * from table where id like '%" . $res[$i]["id"] . "%'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
     //print_r( $row);
     echo $row["name"];
    }

Comment: you can use my code make an empty variable for example $r=""; and replace echo with if($i==0){$r=$res[$i][0].",";} else {$r.=",".$res[$i][0];}

Comment: then your sql will be select * from table where id  IN($r)